# Nothing happens after starting a Java Web start app

Tags: java

I've never done a Java Web start application before. I wrote my app's JNLP files and published them along with all the JARs to my Web server. However, after getting the initial splash screen where JWS loads the libraries, nothing happens. Do you have any suggestions on how to debug this, perhaps get some console output? I've tried cleaning the cache through "javaws -uninstall" but it doesn't help.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Java Console you should enable full tracing and logging.  This will tell you a lot about what happens under the covers when Web Start doesn't work.

See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html

Hopefully this can get you started.

Answer (score 2):

In the Java Control Panel, select Advanced > Java console > Show console. You will probably see some exception output. If the process is still running, you should be able to find it with `jps` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still nothing. Console is enabled, but nothing appears. On my other computer it appears for just a sec, and it doesn't show any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the task manager to see if it had actually launched?

In my experience with a similar problem, the program itself was actually running, but it wasn't able to display anything.